# How to configure two authentication manager, for authenticating client and user respectively, when using spring security oauth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

i am new to spring security, and trying to configure two authentication manager for authenticating client and user respectively with the following configuration. However, it keeps showing me "No client with requested id: admin" in log file. Can expert advise? Thanks.

configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </security:http>

    <!-- authentication manager for user -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="inMemoryUserSerivce" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:user-service id="inMemoryUserSerivce">
        <security:user name="admin" password="Abcd1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <!-- specify API client applications -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="mobile_android" secret="secret123" authorized-grant-types="password"
                      authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" redirect-uri="http://localhost:8080/oauth2_callbak" />
    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity and other things -->
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

log file exception message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException: No client with requested id: admin
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.InMemoryClientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(InMemoryClientDetailsService.java:36)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(ClientDetailsUserDetailsService.java:44)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
```